# ¿Cómo envío parámetros por medio de una función utilizando ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

¿Alguno sabe como dejo el COD_COMPRA de cada compra en el botón? la función de ConsultarProductosxCompra debe recibir ese parametro y no sé como enviarselo, he consultado pero no encuentro nada. Actualmente lo tengo así y revisando en el navegador veo que me llega el COD_COMPRA a la vista, pero cuando doy clic en el botón y reviso que parametro envió sale indefinido, es decir, nulo.

```
                    <tr class="paginationclass" ng-repeat="datalist in listacompra">
                        <td>{{ datalist.FECHA_COMPRA | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
                        <td>{{ datalist.NOMBRE_PROVEEDOR | uppercase}}</td>
                        <td>{{ datalist.VALOR_COMPRA | uppercase}}</td>
                        <td>{{ datalist.NOMBRE_PAGO | uppercase}}</td>
                        <td>{{ datalist.FECHA_LIMITEPAGO | date  : shortDate}}</td>
                        <td>{{ datalist.CUOTAS }}</td>
                        <td><button ng-click="ConsultarProductosxCompra({{datalist.COD_COMPRA}})">Ver productos</button></td>
                    </tr>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que pasa es que dentro ng-click escribes codigo javascript sin necesidad de interpolación por defecto, funciona de manera similar a onclick="expresion js". Solo que ng-click al estar dentro de un ng-repeat reconoce los datos de datalist, tambien cualquier variable dentro del controlador se podría usar.

Es vez de utilizar:

`ng-click="ConsultarProductosxCompra({{datalist.COD_COMPRA}})";`

utiliza:

```
ng-click="ConsultarProductosxCompra(datalist.COD_COMPRA)";
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar por qué? Una respuesta tan breve difícilmente puede ayudar si no la acompañas de una justificación.

Comment: @fedorqui lo que pasa es que dentro ng-click escribes codigo javascript sin necesidad de interpolación  por defecto, funciona de manera similar a onclick="expresion js". Solo que ng-click al estar dentro de un ng-repeat reconoce los datos de datalist, tambien cualquier variable dentro del controlador se podría usar.

Comment: Qué interesante, Donato. Tal vez será más útil si le das a [edit] y añades estos detalles útiles en la publicación en sí. Lee si puedes el [tour] y [ask].